# Dynamically (without knowing the name of columns) calculating an new column based on other columns using python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a python dataframe that is dynamically built (implying that we can't forsee the number and name of the columns).

What I would like to do is to create a new column Verified that is calculating according to the following:

```
ABS((MAX(A,B,C)-MIN(A,B,C))/(MAX(A,B,C) or MIN(A,B,C) or 1))
```

- |a | b| c | verified
- |1 | 2| 3 | 0.666
- |-1|-2|-3 | 2

Remember that the columns could have another name and another number of columns (the following must also be supported):
ABS((MAX(e,f)-MIN(e,f))/(MAX(e,f) or MIN(e,f) or 1))

- |e |f |verified
- |4 |2 |0.5

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
df['verified'] = df.max(1).sub(df.min(1)).div(df.max(1) | df.min(1) | 1).abs()
```

Demo:

```
In [117]: df
Out[117]:
    a   b   c
0  19   7   9
1   1  11   5
2  18   5  17
3   0   2   4
4  14   1   6
5   6  19  10
6  14   4   9
7   5  12  18
8  18   1  18
9  18   7  14

In [118]: df['verified'] = df.max(1).sub(df.min(1)).div(df.max(1) | df.min(1) | 1).abs()

In [119]: df
Out[119]:
    a   b   c  verified
0  19   7   9  0.521739
1   1  11   5  0.909091
2  18   5  17  0.565217
3   0   2   4  0.800000
4  14   1   6  0.866667
5   6  19  10  0.565217
6  14   4   9  0.666667
7   5  12  18  0.565217
8  18   1  18  0.894737
9  18   7  14  0.478261
```

for your sample data sets:

```
In [121]: df
Out[121]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1 -1 -2 -3

In [122]: df['verified'] = df.max(1).sub(df.min(1)).div(df.max(1) | df.min(1) | 1).abs()

In [123]: df
Out[123]:
   a  b  c  verified
0  1  2  3  0.666667
1 -1 -2 -3  2.000000

In [125]: df
Out[125]:
   e  f
0  4  2

In [126]: df['verified'] = df.max(1).sub(df.min(1)).div(df.max(1) | df.min(1) | 1).abs()

In [127]: df
Out[127]:
   e  f  verified
0  4  2  0.285714
```

check:

```
In [129]: (4 - 2) / (4 | 2 | 1)
Out[129]: 0.2857142857142857
```